# connect by clause in regex_substr

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I cant get the understanding of this statement - not eveN after googling around

```
 
pv_no_list :='23,34,45,56';
SELECT   DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR (pv_no_list,
                                                     '[^,]+',
                                                     1,
                                                     LEVEL)
                                         no_list
                      FROM   DUAL
                CONNECT BY   REGEXP_SUBSTR (pv_no_list,
                                            '[^,]+',
                                            1,
                                            LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The "abuse" (as Colin 't Hart put it) of `connected by` has a good purpose here:
by using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` you can extract only one of the 4 matches (23,34,45,56): the regex `[^,]+` matches any character sequence in the string which does not contain a comma.

If you'll try running:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('23,34,45,56','[^,]+') as "token" 
FROM   DUAL
```

you'll get `23`.

and if you'll try running:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('23,34,45,56','[^,]+',1,1) as "token"
FROM   DUAL
```

you'll also get `23` only that now we also set *[two additional parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm)*: start looking in position 1 (which is the default), and return the 1st occurrence.

Now lets run:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('23,34,45,56','[^,]+',1,2) as "token"
FROM   DUAL
```

this time we'll get `34` (2nd occurrence) and using `3` as the last parameter will return `45` and so on.

The use of recursive `connected by` along with `level` makes sure you'll receive all the relevant results (not necessarily in the original order though!):

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('23,34,45,56','[^,]+',1,LEVEL) as "token"
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('23,34,45,56','[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
order by 1
```

will return:

```
TOKEN
23
34
45
56
```

which not only contains all 4 results, but also breaks it into separate rows in the resultset!

If you'll **[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/18267)** with it - it might give you a clearer view of the subject.

Comment: Minor detail, where it says "this time we'll get 43" it is actually 34

Comment: @EduCastrillon thanks it was a typo - we don't have 43 here in the sequence ;)

Comment: which condition is better for level? a. CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('23,34,45,56','[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL OR b. REGEXP_COUNT('23,34,45,56', ',')

Comment: @Nir Alfasi how if I want to display in 1 single row with comma separator?

Comment: @user2102665 now that's a different question, I think that [pivot](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/database/sql-11g-pivot.html) should do the trick but I haven't tried it out.

Answer (score 6):

`connect by` has nothing to do with `regex_substr`:

- The first is to perform a hierarchical query, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm
- The second is to get a substring using regular expressions.

This query "abuses" the `connect by` functionality to generate rows in a query on `dual`.
As long as the expression passed to `connect by` is true, it will generate a new row and increase the value of the pseudo column `LEVEL`.

Then `LEVEL` is passed to `regex_substr` to get the nth value when applying the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('23,34,45,56','[^,]+',1,LEVEL) as "token"
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('23,34,45,56','[^,]+',1,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
order by 1
```

@alfasin: Order by 1, it is throwing error for me. "missing right paranthesis"
Also if I skip this then when I call the oracle procedure it gives error "ORA-22950: cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method"