# SQL using Count, with same "Like" multiple times in same cell

Tags: sql, oracle, count, cell, sql-like

I'm trying to get a count on how many times BNxxxx has been commented in the comments cell. So far, I can make each cell be counted once, but there may be multiple comments in a cell containing BNxxxx.

For example, this:

```
------- 
BN0012
------- 
BN0012
------- 
BN0012
BN0123
-------
```

should show an output of BN0012 3 times and BN0123 once. Instead, I get BN0012 3 times only.

Here's my code:

```
select COMMENTS, count(*) as TOTAL 
from NOTE 
Where COMMENTS like '%BN%' AND CREATE_DATE between '01/1/2015' AND '11/03/2015'
group by COMMENTS
order by Total desc;
```

Any ideas?

edit

My code now looks like

```
select BRIDGE_NO, count(*)
from IACD_ASSET b join 
IACD_NOTE c
on c.COMMENTS like concat(concat('BN',b.BRIDGE_NO),'%')
Where c.CREATE_DATE between '01/1/2015' AND '11/03/2015' AND length(b.BRIDGE_NO) > 1 
group by b.BRIDGE_NO
order by count(*);
```

Problem with this is the BN44 is the same as BN4455 .. have tried concat(concat('BN',b.BRIDGE_NO),'_') comes back with nothing , any ideas how i can get exact likes

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: yaya, but i want results that show i guess a full break down of BN, not just the first occurrence in a cell..

Comment: I updated my answer per your edits to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your `COMMENTS` table has a primary key column (such as `comment_id`) or at least that `comments` isn't a `CLOB`. If it is a `CLOB` then you're not going to be able to use `GROUP BY` on that column.

You can accomplish this as follows without even a lookup table of `BN....` values. No guarantees as to the performance:

```
WITH d1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS comment_id, 'BN0123 is a terrible thing BN0121 also BN0000' AS comments
         , date'2015-01-03' AS create_date
      FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS comment_id, 'BN0125 is a terrible thing BN0120 also BN1000' AS comments
         , date'2015-02-03' AS create_date
      FROM dual
)
SELECT comment_id, comments, COUNT(*) AS total FROM (
    SELECT comment_id, comments, TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(comments, '(^|\s)BN\d+(\s|$)', 1, LEVEL, 'i')) AS bn
      FROM d1
     WHERE create_date >= date'2015-01-01'
       AND create_date < date'2015-11-04'
   CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(comments, '(^|\s)BN\d+(\s|$)', 1, LEVEL, 'i') IS NOT NULL
       AND PRIOR comment_id = comment_id
       AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL
) GROUP BY comment_id, comments;
```

Note that I corrected your filter:

```
CREATE_DATE between '01/1/2015' AND '11/03/2015'
```

First, you should be using ANSI date literals (e.g., `date'2015-01-01'`); second, using `BETWEEN` for dates is often a bad idea as Oracle `DATE` values contain a time portion. So this should be rewritten as:

```
    create_date >= date'2015-01-01'
AND create_date < date'2015-11-04'
```

Note that the later date is November *4*, to make sure we capture all possible comments that were made on November *3*.

If you want to see the matched comments without aggregating the counts, then do the following (taking out the outer query, basically):

```
WITH d1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS comment_id, 'BN0123 is a terrible thing BN0121 also BN0000' AS comments
         , date'2015-01-03' AS create_date
      FROM dual
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS comment_id, 'BN0125 is a terrible thing BN0120 also BN1000' AS comments
         , date'2015-02-03' AS create_date
      FROM dual
)
SELECT comment_id, comments, TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(comments, '(^|\s)BN\d+(\s|$)', 1, LEVEL, 'i')) AS bn
  FROM d1
 WHERE create_date >= date'2015-01-01'
   AND create_date < date'2015-11-04'
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(comments, '(^|\s)BN\d+(\s|$)', 1, LEVEL, 'i') IS NOT NULL
   AND PRIOR comment_id = comment_id
   AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL;
```

---

Given the edits to your question, I think you want something like the following:

```
SELECT b.bridge_no, COUNT(*) AS comment_cnt
  FROM iacd_asset b INNER JOIN iacd_note c
    ON REGEXP_LIKE(c.comments, '(^|\W)BN' || b.bridge_no || '(\W|$)', 'i')
 WHERE c.create_dt >= date'2015-01-01'
   AND c.create_dt < date'2015-03-12' -- It just struck me that your dates are dd/mm/yyyy
   AND length(b.bridge_no) > 1
 GROUP BY b.bridge_no
 ORDER BY comment_cnt;
```

Note that I am using `\W` in the regex above instead of `\s` as I did earlier to make sure that it captures things like `BN1234/BN6547`.

Comment: Very interesting! I had never seen `connect by regex_substr` used like this. For anyone interested in more info this pattern and how it works you can check out alfasin's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195280/connect-by-clause-in-regex-substr

Comment: Why is the `AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL` needed?

Comment: If you omit it, you get a cartesian join. I don't really understand why, personally, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem.  Let me assume that you have a table of all known BN values that you care about.  Then you can do something like:

```
select bn.fullbn, count(*)
from tableBN bn join
     comments c
     on c.comment like ('%' || bn.fullbn || '%')
group by bn.fullbn;
```

The performance of this might be quite slow.

If you happen to be storing lists of things in the comment field, then this is a very bad idea.  You should not store lists in strings; you should use a junction table.

Comment: I think this will be the solution, just getting some oracle syntax errors, which i assume is to do with how the join is being performed or the concat command

Comment: This is working, with , instead of pipes.. With the like statement, i want comments that have "BN" before the number, as the BN table only has numbers. i tried ('BN',b.BRIDGE_NO, '%'), dosnt seem to give the desired result. any ideas

Comment: Use ('%BN' || bn.fullbn || '%')

Comment: hey psarag12, thank for that, did try that the problem with this is the BN44 is the same as BN4455

Comment: @cain2060, that is why I would suggest using regexes instead of simple `LIKE`. `LIKE` can't be made to be greedy, so it won't choose to match `BN4455` over `BN44`.

Answer (score -1):

Try use the distinct keyword in your select statement, to pull in unique values for the comments. Like this:

```
select distinct COMMENTS, count(*) as TOTAL 
from NOTE 
Where COMMENTS like '%BN%' AND CREATE_DATE between '01/1/2015' AND    
'11/03/2015'
group by COMMENTS
order by Total desc;
```