# How to split a comma-separated value to columns using connect by

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a column with less than <50 comma separated values. And the number of comma separated values in that particular column is not constant I would like to query this table with IN/AND/OR clause for these comma separated values:

So I would like to:

- split these values into separate columns in the select query
- Query for a person's market code with AND, OR and IN :

  - EUP and APCAC
  - APAC or EU Or CA
  - IN ( APAC,EU,LATIM)

I have to use this query in spring data jpa native query

**I don't want to use as many substr.**

I thought to accomplish this by using connect by with level would be useful after referring the following answers - [ans1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464275/split-comma-separated-values-to-columns-in-oracle) and [ans2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195280/connect-by-clause-in-regex-substr)

Usertable:

| username | market_code | in_use |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | eup,apac,Latim | 0 |
| sebastin | apac,Latim | 0 |
| xavier | ca,apac,Latim | 0 |

However the following only returns one row where I expected to have 3 rows :

```
select regexp_substr(market_code,'[^|]+', 1, level) from testautomadm.userpool
where  AND USERNAME = 'john'
connect by regexp_substr('market_code', '[^|]+', 1, level)  
is not null
```

Any help to solve this use case much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `multiset` and hierarchy query as follows:

```
Select user_name, 
       listagg(market_code, ',') within group (order by pos) as market_code,
       In_use
  From
(Select user_name, 
       regexp_substr(market_code, '[^,]+',1, column_value) as market_code, 
       in_use,
       column_value as pos
  From t,
       table(cast(multiset(
         select level from dual 
         connect by level <= length (regexp_replace(t.market_code, '[^,]+'))  + 1
        ) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels) t
  Where market_code in ('EUP','APCAC')
  Group by user_name, in_use
  Having count(distinct market_code) = 2
```

Above query shows the usage of `AND` as we have used `count = 2` You can use `count = 1` and respective market_code in `IN` for `OR` And `IN` query

Comment: Thank you. It took some time for comprehending your answer. This solves the purpose .